# Set an initial value for a Javascript Count Down Timer

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a countdown timer that starts with the click of a button.

I have gotten this to work for minutes and seconds but cannot seem to figure out how to get the static time to display prior to the button click.

What I am wondering is how would I get the time to display on the webpage above the start button (in this case 59 min 59 sec) and start the countdown function once the button is hit?

```
<head>
<input type="button" onclick="countdown('countdown');" value="Start" />
<script type="text/javascript">
var cdtime;
var minutes = 59;
var seconds = 59;

function countdown(element) {
    cdtime = setInterval(function() {
        var timer = document.getElementById(element);
        if(seconds == 0) {
            if(minutes == 0) {
                alert(timer.innerHTML = "countdown's over!");                    
                clearInterval(cdtime);
                return;
            } else {
                minutes--;
                seconds = 60;
            }
        }
        if(minutes > 0) {
            var minutetxt = minutes + (minutes > 1 ? ' minutes' : 'minute');
        } else {
            var minutetxt = '';
        }
        var secondstxt;
        if(seconds > 1) {
            secondstxt = 'seconds'; 
        } else { 
            secondstxt = 'second';
        }

        timer.innerHTML = minutetxt + ' ' + seconds + ' ' + secondstxt;
        seconds--;
    }, 1000);
}
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id='countdown'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why can't you just type the static time in manually or do something on pageload with javascript to put it there? The innerHTML update should just replace the text

Comment: Ryan, did you find any of the answers useful? Did any of them answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

- create a div and use set inner html of that div using JavaScript (I did it after defining minutes and seconds).
- Also bring your elements out of header and bring them inside body
- if you don't use jquery to wait for window to complete loading, bring your script after all html elements.

```js
    var cdtime;
    var minutes = 59;
    var seconds = 59; 
    document.getElementById("initialtime").innerHTML=minutes+":"+seconds;

function countdown(element) {
    cdtime = setInterval(function() {
        var timer = document.getElementById(element);
        if(seconds == 0) {
            if(minutes == 0) {
                alert(timer.innerHTML = "countdown's over!");                    
                clearInterval(cdtime);
                return;
            } else {
                minutes--;
                seconds = 60;
            }
        }
        if(minutes > 0) {
            var minutetxt = minutes + (minutes > 1 ? ' minutes' : 'minute');
        } else {
            var minutetxt = '';
        }
        var secondstxt;
            if(seconds > 1)
            {
            secondstxt = 'seconds'; 
            }
            else
            { 
            secondstxt = 'second';
            }


        timer.innerHTML = minutetxt + ' ' + seconds + ' ' + secondstxt;
        seconds--;
    }, 1000); }
```

```html
<body> 
<div id="initialtime"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="countdown('countdown');" value="Start" />
<div id='countdown'></div> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put `59:59` right in the div, then start the count down timer from `60*60-2 (59:58)`. Also you have the start button in the `<head>` of the document. Here is an [**example**](http://pastebin.com/vRA7BtfA) of how to get your code [**working**](http://jsfiddle.net/robbmj/oq5sj9mt/) quickly.

However if you need/want to set the initial value of the `div` with JavaScript here are some options and a few additional improvements; including a more accurate timer function that is also reusable.

```js
function startTimer(duration, displayFtn) {
  var start = Date.now(), diff, obj;
  (function timer() {
    diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);
    obj = minutesSeconds(diff);
    displayFtn(obj.minutes, obj.seconds);
    if (diff > 0) {
      setTimeout(timer, 200);
    }
  }());  
}

function minutesSeconds(duration) {
  return {
    'minutes': (duration / 60) | 0,
    'seconds': (duration % 60) | 0
  };
}

// we need to wait for the page to load before we can select any DOM elements
window.onload = function() {
  var duration = 5, // set to 60*60-1 for 59 minutes and 59 seconds
      display1 = document.querySelector('#countdown1'),
      display2 = document.querySelector('#countdown2'),
      startTime = minutesSeconds(duration);

  // here is where the initial values are set
  format1(startTime.minutes, startTime.seconds);
  format2(startTime.minutes, startTime.seconds);

  // here we add an event listenter this is called when the buttons is clicked 
  document.querySelector('#startcountdown1').addEventListener('click', listener);
  document.querySelector('#startcountdown2').addEventListener('click', listener);
  
  function listener(event) {
    // we don't want to start the count down twice for the same button,
    // so remove the listener
    event.target.removeEventListener('click', listener);
    var formatter = event.target.id == 'startcountdown1' ? format1 : format2;
    startTimer(duration, formatter);
  }
  
  // these two functions just format the remaining minutes and
  // seconds differently
  function format1(minutes, seconds) {
    minutes = minutes + (minutes > 1 ? ' minutes' : ' minute');
    seconds = seconds + (seconds > 1 ? ' seconds' : ' second');
    display1.textContent = minutes + ' ' + seconds;
  }

  function format2(minutes, seconds) {
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    display2.textContent = minutes + ':' + seconds;
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Start Count Down 1" id='startcountdown1' />
<div id='countdown1'></div>
<hr />
<input type="button" value="Start Count Down 2" id='startcountdown2' />
<div id='countdown2'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options - put the time in the html initially

```
<div id='countdown'>59 minutes 59 seconds</div>
```

The other option if you want more flexibility down the road is to set it using javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function initialize() {
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "59 minutes 59 seconds";

  }

  intialize();
})
```

With the second option you could replace the text with code that returns the string, or separate out your string generation code into a separate function that you call.

Answer (score 0):

// Where eventDate = event start date `enter event start date`

eventStartsIn = (eventDate: Date) => {
        const today = moment().format();

```
    const actualStartEvent = moment(eventDate).format();

    if (today < actualStartEvent) {
        const todayDate = moment(today);
        const actualDate = moment(actualStartEvent);
        const dayDiffrence = actualDate.diff(todayDate, 'days');
        if (dayDiffrence === 0) {
            const timeDiff = moment.utc(moment(actualDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').diff(moment(
                todayDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'))).format('HH:mm');
            const hours = moment.duration(timeDiff).hours();
            const min = moment.duration(timeDiff).minutes();
            return `In ${hours >= 1 ? timeDiff : min} ${hours >= 1 ? `${hours > 1 ? 'hours' : 'hour'}` :
                'minutes'}`;
        }
        return `In ${dayDiffrence} ${dayDiffrence > 1 ? 'days' : 'day'}`;
    }

    if (today > actualStartEvent) {
        const todayDate = moment(today);
        const actualDate = moment(actualStartEvent);
        const dayDiffrence = actualDate.diff(todayDate, 'days');
        if (dayDiffrence === 0) {
            const timeDiff = moment.utc(moment(todayDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').diff(moment(
                actualDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'))).format('HH:mm');
            const hours = moment.duration(timeDiff).hours();
            const min = moment.duration(timeDiff).minutes();
            return `${hours >= 1 ? timeDiff : min} ${hours >= 1 ? `${hours > 1 ? 'hours' : 'hour'}` :
                'minutes'} Ago`;
        }
        return `${Math.abs(dayDiffrence)} ${Math.abs(dayDiffrence) > 1 ? 'days' : 'day'} Ago`;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This will may not be updating on every second. Hope you this idea will help you.